# symfony2 group by date query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Code is as follows, trying to group transactions by date. If I use GROUP BY YEAR(t.createdDate), MONTH(t.createdDate), DAY(t.createdDate)

I get teh following error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 173 near 'YEAR(t.creat': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

```
$transactions = $em->createQuery("SELECT SUM(t.amount) as amount, COUNT(t.id) as total FROM XXXCreatorMainBundle:Transaction t WHERE t.createdDate >= :createdStart AND t.createdDate <= :createdStop")
                           ->setParameter('createdStart',$createdStart)
                           ->setParameter('createdStop',$createdStop)
                           ->getResult();
```

I just need to show the total # of transactions and sum of the amounts in a day by day fashion.. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those functions come build-in `Doctrine`, so so must either register them manually or install `DoctrineExtensions` from [GitHub](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) repo as I'm sure that it has all of them prepared for use.

Also, take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.simukti.net/blog/2012/04/05/how-to-select-year-month-day-in-doctrine2/) (last code block, to be more precise) on how to register functions from `DoctrineExtensions`.

Hope this helps....

Comment: thank you so much. i still was unable to ORDER BY YEAR(t.createdDate) for example, but i did a select YEAR(t.createdDate) as year and then did ORDER BY year... so it worked out in the end.